# import firebase generated json dataset to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my approach: exporting firebase data as json and insert them to mongodb using

```
mongoimport --db firebase --collection examples --file examples.json --jsonArray
```

i am using --jsonArray on linux since without it on linux it showed error `mongodb supplied JSON is too large` but that is another story.

after inserting data to mongodb my data looks like 
[my data after importing to mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW1Ht.jpg)
so what i am trying to do is to import the data and let the _id in mongodb be the key of my firebase childrens
I would like to achive this using default tools and not a work around like parsing the data using java and then insert them to mongodb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created a hibernate persistance to insert data to mongoDB hope that help somebody. Still a work around but it helped